# How to create a Button that Changes the Color of Different Elements with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, onclick

I'm trying to create a button that, when clicked, change the elements of a page to different colors combinations.

For example, when the body is 'red' and the main titles are 'yellow', the alternate titles and the border lines are 'red', and the alternate background is 'yellow'.

The colors seem to be changing randomly instead of having an order, and I can't change the 'border-bottom' color.

```js
// Main titles color change

var colors = ["yellow", "red", "blue"];
var colorIndex = 0;
  
function changeText() {
    var col = document.getElementsByClassName("textcolor");
    if (colorIndex >= colors.length) {
      colorIndex = 0;
    }
for(var i = 0; i < col.length; i++){
    col[i].style.color = colors[colorIndex];
    }
    colorIndex++;
    }

// Body background color change
  
var colors = ["red", "blue", "yellow"];
var colorIndex = 0;

function changeBackground() {
 var col = document.getElementsByClassName("bodycolor");
 if (colorIndex >= colors.length) {
   colorIndex = 0;
    }
for(var i = 0; i < col.length; i++){
    col[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
    }
    colorIndex++;
    }

   
// Alternate titles and borders color change

var colors = ["red", "blue", "yellow"];
var colorIndex = 0;
  
function changeTextAlt() {
    var col = document.getElementsByClassName("alt-textcolor");
    if (colorIndex >= colors.length) {
      colorIndex = 0;
    }
for(var i = 0; i < col.length; i++){
    col[i].style.color = colors[colorIndex];
    }
    colorIndex++;
    }

// Alternate background color change
  
var colors = ["yellow", "red", "blue"];
var colorIndex = 0;

function changeBackgroundAlt() {
    var col = document.getElementsByClassName("alt-backgroundcolor");
    if (colorIndex >= colors.length) {
      colorIndex = 0;
    }
for(var i = 0; i < col.length; i++){
    col[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
    }
    colorIndex++;
    }
```

```css
body{
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.66667;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',Arial,sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    }
 

.textcolor{
    color: #000;
}

.bodycolor{
    background-color: #fff;
}

.alt-textcolor{
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.alt-backgroundcolor{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<body class='bodycolor'>

<button type="button" onclick="changeBackground();changeText();changeTextAlt();changeBackgroundAlt();">Click me</button>

<p class='textcolor'>This is a title</p>

<div class='alt-backgroundcolor'>

<p class='alt-textcolor'>This is an alternate title 1</p>
<p class='alt-textcolor'>This is an alternate title 2</p>
<p class='alt-textcolor'>This is an alternate title 3</p>
<p class='alt-textcolor'>This is an alternate title 4</p>
</div>

<div class='bodycolor'>

<p class='textcolor'>This is another title</p>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: You're redeclaring `var colorIndex = 0;`a bunch of times, and changing it in all functions. That's an error, and not going to work as intended. Either use a different variable for each color array, or change the variable once, then update all colors accordingly when the button is clicked. (also, in general, when you find yourself copy-pasting a bunch of code multiple times, you should use a function instead)

Comment: Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/athj702b/

Comment: Hey Chris! Thanks for the help, but when I clicked the colors went all random. See here: https://prnt.sc/pguxxp

Comment: My code isn't supposed to generate the exact color scheme you're looking for; it's mostly supposed to show how to avoid duplicate code. Change the offset numbers in the `changeAttrForCls()` calls to set different initial colors.

Comment: Ah ok, but do you know how to make the color pairings as mentioned? How do I make it change to the exact colors I want?

Comment: I changed the initial index to `-1`, that way the offset reflects exactly the color index after the first click. So use 0 for yellow, 1 for red, 2 for blue.